# remove dotnet-sdk-2.0.0 in ubuntu - nuget fallback folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dotnet-sdk

I have installed on Ubuntu 16.04 the dotnet-sdk-2.0.0 but the I wanted to remove it and on my hard disk is left a folder with 1Gb of data (/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder).

Can I just delete it from the hard disk with admin permission? 
Is it safe or will have some crash in the OS? 
What is the correct procedure to remove the dotnet-sdk? (I used apt purge).

Comment: I just deleted the folder with admin permission (sudo nautilus /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder) and had no problems.